# Licensing under author name?

Tags: publications, publishability, license

What does it means a project being licensed with the name of the author?

I mean, one instance is: there is an author X, that writes an open source book on biology with git and at the end of the README file is **© 2017 X**. Other instance is when the same author X, writes his webpage and at the end of the page put his characteristic **© 2017 X**.

It is evident author does not get into the game of licenses (justified or not!!). But what should I interpret with his license? Every change (in any sense) that I want to make I should contact him? What is the (legal status) point of this license "**© 2017 X**"??

Example of [webpage](http://peterlefanulumsdaine.com/)

Comment: _Every change (in any sense) that I want to make_ Please clarify change on what and what change you want to make. For now, vote to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to academia at all. It is likely on-topic on [law.se] and perhaps on [opensource.se]. Note that you seem to have some big misconceptions about how copyright and licensing works and it will probably help to read some basic material on the matter before asking a question, be it only to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

A statement such as this "© 2017 X"  means that the author want you to know that he is the author of this page, and that he has the copyright over the content of this page. In simple words, this means that this is some original content and that it belongs to him.

If you want to copy some of that content in your own webpage, book, or other documents, or modify it then you should do it in a way that will respect the copyright law  and the license of the content chosen by the author. If the author does not provide a specific license for his webpage such as Creative Commons, then you should ask the authors about how you can reuse his content and if he agrees or not. You can send an e-mail and ask him if you can modify the content and republish it for example. Maybe he will say yes, maybe no

But beside that, you can still cite his work. For example, if you want to copy a few sentences of text from his webpage, you could use the quotation marks " " and cite his webpage as the source of the text. In this case, you typically don't need to ask the permission for that because you are citing a short part of the text.

By the way, a book can be open-source (you can see the code of the book), but "open-source" does not mean that you are free to do whatever you want with the content. The copyright still belong to the author and you need to follow the license that he choses.